# store local data across runs in dbt

Tags: dbt

In my ETL process, I read data from oracle to load to BigQuery in batches (using sqoop).
I need to track my batch id (or latest updated_date) across runs. That is because, as I push the data downstream, I need to identify which batches are pending (they might not always go downstream in a single run - downstream can fail).

I  was wondering if there was a general purpose metadata db I could use in DBT or do I have to build my own. Something to persist data across run/sessions.

My batch metadata will probably be about 1 million records tracking multiple tables, so storing on BigQuery feels like overkill. Also, single record writes - like 60 every hour (6 runs for 10 different tables)

I could write to a local sqlite db (on dbt container), or local mysql instance but if DBT supports something out of the box, I was hoping to use it.